# jquery slide call on multiple links

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a menu that should slide up when you click a link on the main page to another page. I'm using

```
function menuLoad(){$('#menu').slideUp(600)};

function menuHide(){$('#menu').slideDown(600)};
```

How can I only call the menuLoad() function if the menu is hidden?

Comment: You lost me here "when you click a link on the main page to another page" and here "the menu only loads once and than doesn't work anymore". Please give us some HTML, some click event binding code, while you are at it, give us some cookies (the sweet ones), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(".all-menu-links a").click(function() {
       $thisEl = $(this);
       if ($thisEl.hasClass("home")) {
            $("#menu").slideDown(600);
       } else {
            $("#menu").slideUp(600);
       }
 });
```

Markup structure should be something like this:

```
<div class="all-menu-links">
      <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="members" href="#">Members</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: The menu should only be hidden when I click the home link. On all other links it should be shown. Doesn't this toggle the menu on every link?

Comment: An easy way to handle this then would be to give the links an additional class specifying its role... I'll demonstrate

Comment: Wait... so you want the menu to slide out on page load?

Comment: No. (I'm building a one page site) The menu should be hidden on the main page (div) but slideup when a link to another page (div) is clicked on the main page. It should stay up untill the user returns to the main page (div)

Comment: Is this new version getting closer?